# Unable to forward Request to URI with context-path

Tags: java, spring-boot, reverse-proxy, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am unable to forward my request to a URI with contextpath.

For example I am requesting my Spring cloud gateway server with

```
http://localhost:1010/mygateway/server/date
```

And I expect it to forward to

```
http://myapiserver.com/xyzapi/v1/server/date
```

But It gives me 404

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
            .route("api-server-date", r -> r.host("**")
                    .and()
                    .path("/mygateway/server/date")
                    .filters(f -> f.stripPrefix(1))
                    .uri("https://myapiserver.com/xyzapi/v1"))
            .build();
}
```

It works when I change my configuration to this

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
            .route("api-server-date", r -> r.host("**")
                    .and()
                    .path("/mygateway/xyzapi/v1/server/date")
                    .filters(f -> f.stripPrefix(1))
                    .uri("https://myapiserver.com"))
            .build();
}
```

I don't know what configuration I am providing wrong. It should work.

All I want is to use

```
https://myapiserver.com/xyzapi/v1
```

As my URI. Meaning all Incoming traffic to my spring cloud gateway server should forward to this URL after appending the incoming url

Kindly suggest what is wrong ? Or is it something not possible with Spring Cloud Gateway ?

Comment: Are you setting a context path using something equivalent to `server.servlet.context-path`? It seems that way but its not clear to me.

Comment: Yes In my actual API server I am setting that @RobEvans

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want (looking at online samples) is:

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
  String requestHandlerUrl = "http://myapiserver.com/xyzapi/v1/server/date";
  return builder.routes()
          .route("api-server-date", r -> r.host("**")
             .and()
             .path("/mygateway/server/date")
             .filters(f -> f.stripPrefix(1))
             .uri(requestHandlerUrl)
          .build();
}
```

... so that requests made to whatever host your app is deployed on are forwarded/passed to `requestHandlerUrl` as the destination.

It looks as if `/mygateway/server/date` is the "shortcut" or alias for the URL you actually want to handle the request.

Some examples here: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/multi/multi__configuration.html#_fluent_java_routes_api

Comment: As I told you that is not working !

I have tried that also. It is giving me 404.
And it is making a request to http://myapiserver.com/xyzapi/v1/server/date/server/date
I am not able to see the outgoing request but seeing 404 I am pretty sure that is the issue

I think somehow it is appending /server/date in requestHandlerUrl

Comment: Seems likely pretty close to a solution in that case... try remove `server/date` from `requestHandlerUrl` and try it. If it does not work, add it back in and change `.path("/mygateway/server/date")` to `.path("/mygateway")` one of them is adding an additional `/server/date` to the final URL and can be removed by the looks of things

Comment: Your suggested requestHandlerUrl should be this http://myapiserver.com/xyzapi/v1

I want all the request coming to my SCG to forward to this requestURL by appending some part of the incoming request.

Also I want to give access to few selected apis only hence directly appending /server/date in requestHandlerUrl is not feasible or correct